# sql find parent table where sum of child column not equal to parent column

Tags: sql

hey guys i am trying to find the a bill from billMaster where the sum of billDetails.total is not equal to billMaster.remainingAmount

**NB**
this is a one to many relationship where one bill can contain more billdetails

i tried the below query and got an sql error

```
/* SQL Error (1111): Invalid use of group function */


SELECT a.id AS billMAsterId FROM eBillMaster AS a JOIN eBillDetail AS b ON a.id = b.billId
WHERE SUM(b.total) !=  b.remainAmount GROUP BY a.id 


SELECT a.remainAmount, a.id AS BillId FROM eBillMaster a JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM eBillMaster) b JOIN eBillDetail c ON (a.id - c.billId) WHERE SUM(c.total) != a.remainAmount
```

both  queries returned the same error i gess its on how i used the sum on where close.
But the sad thing is that i cant sole the problem..
Any response will be appreciated.

now assume i want to get recent user bill that meets the above condition . Note the billMaster has a column called user_id. how will the new query look like.

Comment: The answer will depend on the DBMS you are using: Oracle? SQL Server? MySql? Also, the fact that you're asking this question indicates a flaw in the database design. Derived or calculated values (like remainAmount) should not be stored in the database at all.

Comment: am using mysql and thanks for the enlightenment

Comment: How would we know what constitutes as "recent"? Is it the higher user_id column? You should provide an example of the data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every one for your feedback it led me to the correct path and the modified query is

```
    SELECT m.propertyId, d.sumTotal, m.remainAmount, m.id
FROM eBillMaster AS m JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM eBillMaster GROUP BY propertyId) b USING (id)
JOIN (select billId, sum(total) sumTotal from eBillDetail group by billId) AS d ON m.id = d.billId
WHERE d.sumTotal != m.remainAmount;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is standard SQL, Aggregated values are filtered in the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT a.id AS billMAsterId 
FROM eBillMaster AS a 
JOIN eBillDetail AS b ON a.id = b.billId
GROUP BY a.id, a.remainAmount
HAVING SUM(b.total) != a.remainAmount
```

Some Sql engines allow to omitt `a.remainAmount` from `GROUP BY` when `eBillMaster.id` is PK.
One more (exotic a bit) option

```
SELECT a.id AS billMAsterId 
FROM eBillMaster AS a 
JOIN eBillDetail AS b ON a.id = b.billId
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING SUM(b.total) != AVG(a.remainAmount)
```

Comment: This is wrong! Each line would join master and detail, so sum(a.remainAmount) is not what you want.

Comment: @BrunoCanettieri,  provided `a.id` is a primary key, `SUM(a.remainAmount)` == `a.remainAmount` when `GROUP BY a.id`.

Comment: This is not wrong if `a.id` is *the* primary key (like it seems reasonable to assume). But in this case you can simply write `HAVING SUM(b.total) <> a.remainAmount`, because `remainAmount` functionally depends on the PK and is automatically covered by `GROUP BY a.id` - as per definition in standard SQL, and as implemented in PostgreSQL (at least).

Comment: Hey, sorry. read my comment and it seemed a little aggressive. But I really do believe it is wrong. Take the master as (1, 10) and details with two lines (1, 10) and (1, 10), the join (id, remainamount, total) would appear as (1, 10, 10) and (1, 10, 10), so the group by and sum would return (1, 20, 20) - that in turn will make your query return that this id 1 is a valid response, which it does not seem to be the expected result. Check @Stu answer, it seems that was what you were aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

An example would make thinks much easier, but I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT m.id
FROM eBillMaster AS m 
JOIN (select billId, sum(total) sumTotal from eBillDetail group by billId) AS d ON m.id = d.billId
WHERE d.sumTotal != m.remainAmount;
```

Check it out here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89dcfb/7

Answer (score 0):

It's more efficient tou use a `cross apply` also known as a `lateral join` - depending on your `sql` dialect, you haven't tagged your database

```
select a.id as billMAsterId 
from eBillMaster as a 
cross apply (
    select Sum(total) total
    from eBillDetail as b
    where b.billId = a.id 
)b
where a.remainAmount != b.total
```

To do the same with `having` clause you can do

```
select a.id as billMAsterId 
from eBillMaster as a 
join eBillDetail as b on a.id = b.billId
group by a.id, a.remainAmount
having Sum(b.total) != a.remainAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the having clause and also group by remainamount

```
with ebillmaster (id) as(
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 2 from dual union all
    select 3 from dual),
ebilldetail (billid, total, remainamount) as(
    select 1, 4, 5 from dual union all
    select 2, 3, 4 from dual union all
    select 3, 3, 3 from dual union all
    select 4, 1, 2 from dual)
SELECT
    a.id AS billmasterid
FROM
    ebillmaster   a
    JOIN ebilldetail   b ON a.id = b.billid
GROUP BY
    a.id,
    b.remainamount
HAVING
    SUM(b.total) != b.remainamount
```